# Storing values with single quote in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, quotes

I started learning PHP coding earlier October, the issue which is causing my trouble is that my users need to store text in the database (**and the text would probably contain single and double quotes**). Whenever, I put a single quote in the text, it'd cause an error. I really need to store single and double quotes, otherwise the users would have errors when their text would contain phrases like: It's my car. For the meanwhile, I turn single quotes to double ones with str_replace.

The query which I use for inserting the text into the database is:
INSERT INTO notes (text) VALUES ('$text')

**Isn't there any fix for it?**

Comment: This question can be closed now as I got my answer. Thank you StackOverflow. It's was quite awesome to have an answer within 2 minutes.

Comment: You should probably use prepared statements rather than trying to escape it yourself. That way, it will just do the right thing independent of the value you provide. There is a good example at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function like `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape the string before storing it into the database.

Comment: Awesome! Got my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please use any of the following concepts:

1. Use the `QUOTE()` function
2. Use escaping